# Identifiy browser language by javascript or java

Tags: javascript, java, browser

I want to identify the browser language by java or javascript. But with the method accept-language i can got the values, but iis not possible to identify the right UI language, if these language is not placed in the first part of the string.

The activated UI Language is de-DE!
Any different Languages are activated, like en, african, ...
The soritng of languages is changed in browser settings (here chrome)

Example 1: de-DE is activated and in the first position of available languages:
de-DE,de;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,af;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,pl;q=0.5

Example 2: de-DE is activated and NOT in the first position of available languages (here at pos. 2):
en,de-DE;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,af;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,pl;q=0.5

Example 3: de-DE is activated and NOT in the first position of available languages (here at the last pos.):
en,af;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,pl;q=0.6,de-DE;q=0.5

JavaScript:

```
function SprachenCheck() {
    if (navigator.language.indexOf("en") > -1) {
      text = 'Dear visitor, welcome on our pages!';
    } else if (navigator.language.indexOf("de") > -1) {
      text = 'Sehr geehrter Besucher, willkommen auf unseren Seiten!';
    }
    var ausgabe = document.getElementById('ausgabe');
    ausgabe.innerHTML = text;
  }
```

Java:

```java
public String getLanguageFromRequest() {
    String metadat = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(metadat)) {
      String[] lArray = metadat.split(",");
      return lArray[0].substring(0,2).toLowerCase();
    } 
  }
```

Comment: What is is issue here? The Javascript function appears to work for English and German/Deutsch in that it chooses the highest rated. It's unclear what the desired behavior is here.

Comment: No, the JS didn't work right - if you change the order in the list of languages in the browser configuration (for example Chrome) and set english at the top position and german (the main language for UI) somewhere in the next positions you will get an english text from browser. So, that is the issue. To get out, witch language is the "main language" no matter, where the are placing.

Comment: In your example 2 English (en) is the main language. It has a weight of 1 by default https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4.